# What is a content node in Freebase?

Tags: freebase, mql

I tried to find answer to what is a content node, couldn't find it. What exactly is a content node in Freebase? Isn't it a topic like others?

Comment: Context?  Where did you see the term and how was it used?  As an aside all topics (/common/topic) are nodes (/type/object), but the reverse is not true.

Comment: Tom, your comment is interesting. Can you please clarify it? I have come across all /common/topic topics that are also of type /type/object. Can you give an example supporting your comment here please?

Comment: Typically no CVT/mediator is a /common/topic. For example, none of the 660K film performances are topic.  One such is http://www.freebase.com/inspect/m/0gch93m

Comment: That is great thanks. Brings up a small question. Why can't these film performances be a topic on their own, I mean a node in the graph? What are they dangling as a node without the /common/topic?

Comment: You are misunderstanding what constitutes a node.  All /type/object instances are nodes (ie basically everything).  The /common/topic nodes are a subset which used as main pages for things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content nodes are nodes that are used as proxies for content blobs like topic descriptions and images. Since this sort of content is stored outside of the Freebase graph it needs these nodes in the graph so that this content can be linked to by topics.

Freebase is in the process of moving topic descriptions into the graph but images remain as content nodes.

You can see the image content node for the topic San Francisco with [the following MQL query](http://tinyurl.com/bqfh53g):

```
{
  "id": "/m/0d6lp",
  "name": null,
  "/common/topic/image": [{}]
}
```

Then, using the IDs from the image content nodes, you can access the images via the API like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/image**/m/04j74yh**